# Another Azure Devops for my current TenantId

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have a tenantid in Azure. 4 subscriptions exist under this tenantid. In Azure Active Directory  --> Enterprize application i want 4 instances of Azure Devops each running for 1 Azure Subscription of this same tenantid.
How to do this?
My question is not valid? 1 Tenantid <--> 1 Organization possible only?

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple organizations within Azure DevOps. This way you can organise your projects for each subscription as you see fit. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/plan-your-azure-devops-org-structure?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fget-started%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops